# Reputation order on reputation history page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, reputation-history

On the 9th at 21:09 a question that I answered was removed and my rep went down 25 points. Earlier in the day (14:56) I gained 25 rep from an answer I posted. Since I got the upvote/accepted answer at 14:56 and the other question was removed at 21:09 (~6 hours later) should the +25 not be showing below the -25? On the 5th I got an upvote on one question and an accept answer on another and that shows the earliest event last and the later event first.

Which way is the correct way it is meant to be listed?

[image]